# how extract word from text in php

Tags: php, cpu-word, extract

How can I extract word from text in php?
or example, I have this string:
`this is a long text string where it is written something`

I want obtain:

```
this
is
long
text
string
where
it 
is written
something
```

Comment: Is `is written` on one line just a typo?

Comment: I'm assuming you want the `a` in the output as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP manual `explode`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

explode by space `' '` would get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try builtin function `explode`

```
$string='this is a long text string where it is written something';
$output = explode(" ", $string);
var_dump($output);
```

it will show your required result